# Norm convergency of rank one projections on $\mathcal{H}$

Tags: operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Suppose $\mathcal{H}$ is a complex Hilbert space and $(x_a)$ is a net of *unit* vectors in $\mathcal{H}$ such that $x_a \to x$. Now let $P_a:=\text{Projection onto }\Bbb{C}x_a$, i.e., $P_a(-) = \langle-, x_a\rangle x_a$ and $P_x:=\text{Projection onto }\Bbb{C}x$.

Then since $||P_ah-P_xh||=||\langle h, x_a\rangle x_a-\langle h, x\rangle x||\to||\langle h, x\rangle x-\langle h, x\rangle x||=0$ for all $h \in \mathcal{H}$, $P_a\xrightarrow{\text{SOT}} P_x$.

Is it true that $P_a \to P_x$ in operator norm? I cannot find any counterexample for that.

Any hint is appreciated. Thanks

**EDIT.** Although it is easy to see the "converse" is FALSE in general: for this consider $\mathcal{H}=\Bbb{C}$ and the sequence of unit vectors $x_n=(-1)^n;n\ge 1$ and $x:=x_0=1$. Then $P_{x_n}=P_{x}; \forall n$ but $(x_n)$ doesn't converge to $x$.

(Here, $P_{x_n}$ denotes the projection onto the subspace $\Bbb{C}x_n$ and $P_x$ is that onto $\Bbb{C}x$)

Comment: What is this SOT thing?

Comment: @DionelJaime SOT:=Strong Operator Topology

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that it is true. For any $h \in \mathcal{H}$ we have
\begin{align}
\|P_a h -P_x h\| &= \|\langle h,x_a\rangle x_a - \langle h,x\rangle x\| \\
&\le \|\langle h,x_a\rangle x_a - \langle h,x_a\rangle x\| + \|\langle h,x_a\rangle x - \langle h,x\rangle x\|\\
&\le |\langle h,x_a\rangle|\|x_a-x\| + |\langle h,x_a-x\rangle|\|x\|\\
&\le \|h\|\|x_a\|\|x_a-x\| + \|h\|\|x_a-x\|\|x\|\\
&\le \|h\|\|x_a-x\|(\|x_a\|+ \|x\|)\\
&\le \|h\|\|x_a-x\|(\|x_a-x\|+ 2\|x\|)
\end{align}
so $$\|P_a -P_x\|\le \|x_a-x\|(\|x_a-x\|+ 2\|x\|) \xrightarrow{a} 0.$$